# Want to update the elements in the last section to reflect the edited values in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using wizard. I want to update the elements in the last section generated by all `DisplayFor` to reflect the edited values so that I can see these value in Summary section. Currently, If step through each section until summary section. I do not see value there. I am not getting an idea how to do this. Anyone please help me here.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OnlineEnrolment", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <h4>BASIC INFO</h4>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group has-success ">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="CoursesStudiedYesNo" style="padding-left:6em;">
                                    @Html.Label("Have you studied before?")
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudiedYesNo, "Yes")<span id="SpacebetweenRadioandText">Yes</span><br />
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudiedYesNo, "No", new { @checked = "checked" })<span id="SpacebetweenRadioandText">No</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ">

                                <div class="CoursesDropdown" style="padding-left:6em;">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoursesStudied, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CoursesStudied, Model.CoursesStudiedList, "Choose the course you have studied here", new { @class = "form-control" })

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoursesStudied, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <button type="button" class="next pull-right">NEXT</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <h4>CONTACT DETAILS</h4>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Phone", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Mobile", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mobileNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mobileNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Street, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Street" } })<br />
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Suburb, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Sub" } })<br />
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "City" } })<br />
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Region, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Region" } })<br />
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Country" } })<br />
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <button type="button" class="previous pull-left">PREVIOUS</button>
                            <button type="button" class="next pull-right">NEXT</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <h4>SELECT A COURSE</h4>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Course", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseName, Model.CourseNameList, "Choose a course", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <button type="button" class="previous pull-left">PREVIOUS</button>
                            <button type="button" class="next pull-right">NEXT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <h4>SUMMARY</h4>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div>
                                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailId)
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailId)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB)
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DOB)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayName("Study History")
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CoursesStudied)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.mobileNumber)
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.mobileNumber)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayName("Address")
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Suburb)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt>
                                        @Html.DisplayName("Selected Course")
                                    </dt>

                                    <dd>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CourseName)
                                    </dd>

                                </dl>
                            </div>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <button type="button" class="previous pull-left">PREVIOUS</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="submit pull-right">SUBMIT</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 

        </div>
    </div>

}
```

script

```
 $('.next').click(function () {
            var container = $(this).closest('.section');
            var isValid = true;
            $.each(container.find('input'), function () {
                $('form').validate().element($(this));
                if (!$(this).valid()) {
                    isValid = false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (isValid) {
                container.next('.section').show().find('input').first().focus();
                container.hide();
            } else {
                container.find('.error').text('please complete fields');
            }           

        });
        $('.previous').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var container = $(this).closest('.section');
            container.prev('.section').show().find('input').first().focus();
            container.hide();
        });
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. The values of all form controls in all sections will be retained (and posted back) when you click the submit button. But if you are wanting to update the elements in the last section generated by all your `DisplayFor(...)` to reflect the edited values, then you need to use javascript to do that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I do not want to submit the value now. I want to display these value in summary section.

Comment: Then you need to update them usingjavascipt (but that is not what you question is asking - suggest you edit it to explain what you want)

Comment: Sure, I will do it now.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, does it make sense now? Please read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor(..)` will display the original values of the model. To update the text in your `<dl>` elements, give them `id` attributes, and then handle the `.change()` event of your form controls to update them, for example

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</dt>
    <dd id="display-name">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailId)</dt>
    <dd id="display-emailid">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailId)</dd>
    ....
```

and then create the scripts to update the text

```
$('#Name').change(function() {
    $('#display-name').text($(this).val());
});
$('#EmailId').change(function() {
    $('#display-emailid').text($(this).val());
});
.... // repeat for other form controls
```

Comment: Thank you so so much.  Currently, If i select any item from dropdown then it shows the value. I want to display text. How can I do that? Please help!

Comment: For a `<select>` you can use `$(....).text($(this).find('option:selected').text());`

Comment: Again big thank you. You solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please have a look on my another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705496/how-to-do-check-box-checked-on-button-click-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment90371858_51705496) if you have some time then.